# Tipo de Dato DECIMAL C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de convertir un string a un numero decimal pero estrictamente debe tener este formato: **%10.2f** y que cumpla con los siguientes requisitos:

Esos requisitos estan mejor especificados en el siguiente link:
https://doc.qodbc.com/qodbc/usa/TableDetails.php?tableName=Transaction
Es el campo Amount.

Lo trato de hacer de esta forma pero no lo consigo:

```
var myDecimal = "14.54";
string Amount = string.Format({0:###,###,###,##0.00##}",Decimal.Parse(myDecimal));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> C#

Tienes que usar esta sintaxis (o hacer una conversión explícita a decimal).

```
decimal bankBalance = 3433.20m;
```

y para float es

```
float bankBalance = 3433.20f;
```

para double

```
double bankBalance = 3444.20;
```

Comment: Este es un sitio en español.

Answer (score 1):

Un tipo de datos decimal no tiene formato, es solo un tipo de datos, el formato representa algo visual que aplicas, por ejemplo en un string.

Lo que menciona el link es que valida la puntuacion pero no quiere decir que debas definirlo de esa forma, mas que nada porque un `decimal` como tipo de dato no tiene formato

Solo tienes que conseguir el tipo decimal unicamente

```
var myDecimal = "14.54";
decimal Amount = Decimal.Parse(myDecimal, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

quizas si debas ver el tema de la cultura que aplica, porque si tienes en Windows configurado para que tome la `coma` como separador de decimales no te va a reconocer el numero si usas el `punto`, por eso en el ejemplo puse una cultura que si usa el `punto` como separador de decimales

Answer (score 0):

Para convertir usa el convert

```
Decimal myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("10.54");
```